# How to skip after_build callback in factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot

I'm facing a problem while creating a factory. I have a factory like:

```
Factory.define :job do |j|
  j.association :service_partner, :factory => :service_partner
  j.price_per_task 1.to_money
  end
  j.after_build{|j| j.project.service_partner_ids = [j.service_partner.id] unless j.service_partner.nil?}
end
```

How can I skip the after_build while creating factory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to have the after_build callback to run occasionally, your best bet is to define a nested factory:

```
Factory.define :job do |j|
  j.association :service_partner, :factory => :service_partner
  j.price_per_task 1.to_money
  end
  factory :job_with_additional_setup do
    j.after_build{|j| j.project.service_partner_ids = [j.service_partner.id] unless j.service_partner.nil?}
  end
end
```

You can then create a normal job by doing `FactoryGirl.create(:job)` or one with the after_build: `FactoryGirl.create(:job_with_additional_setup)`